# how to sort entries in an xml file and print only the top 10 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an xml file with 50 entries

I'm supposed to extract population density and economy and print only the top 10. I extracted the data but not sure how to print only the top 10. Here's what I have so far:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    tree = ET.parse("europe.xml")
    stuff = tree.getroot()
    lst = stuff.findall("country")

   for item in lst:
        gdp = int(item.find("gdppc").text)
        pop = int(item.find("population").text)
        area = float(item.find("area").text)
        economy = [gdp*pop]
        density = float(pop/area)
        print(item.get("name"))
        print(sorted(economy))
        print(f"{density:.2f}")
```

Comment: Write gdp, pop, area, enonomy, density to columns in a pandas dataframe. Then sort the dataframe by the column u want to filter the top 10.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this may work, wasn't able to test because didn't had the .xml file.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("europe.xml")
stuff = tree.getroot()
lst = stuff.findall("country")

data = []

for item in lst:
    gdp = int(item.find("gdppc").text)
    pop = int(item.find("population").text)
    area = float(item.find("area").text)
    economy = [gdp * pop]
    density = float(pop / area)
    data.append([gdp, pop, area, economy, density])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['gdp', 'pop', 'area', 'economy', 'desity'])

df.sort_values(by=['pop'], ascending=False)
```